# C# Remove specific bits from a number

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, byte, bit

I have a byte and the value differs every time and I want to clear the two most significant bits of it.

```
Example of what it could have have:
1100 0110
```

I want to clear 1100 0000 from the number so I end up with 0000 0110.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You do that by applying a bitmask representing bits that need to remain in the number:

```
byte mask = (1 << 6) - 1; // == 0011 1111
```

Then you perform bitwise AND with the number which has to be modified:

```
number = ... // Number to modify
byte mask = (1 << 6) - 1; // == 0011 1111
byte result = number & mask;
```